# React-Native Screen is not generating basic scroll

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm new using ReactNative, I've created a screen with 2-3 components inside. Everything was working good, but later when I added more components... I was expecting see all of them just doing scroll movement but everything is like freeze without any scroll. If I wrap my screen into a `<ScrollView>` works perfect but there is a warning there.

Am I missing something here? My other screens works fine but those use a flatlist, which I don't want to use it in this currently screen.

**Screen**

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Image 
    style={styles.image} 
    preview={{uri: listing.images[0].thumbnailUrl}}
    tint="light"
    uri={listing.images[0].url} 
  />
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <SomeComponent>Hi</SomeComponent>
    <FlatList>...</FlatList>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <SomeComponent>More of these that should generate a scrool</SomeComponent>    
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: what's the warning you are getting with ScrollView? Should work fine.

Comment: @JordanDavis Warning: VirtualizaedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizaedLists-backed container instead. Note: I'm using a FlatList component inside, that is producing this warning.

Comment: Also If I use SectionList instead of FlatList I'm getting the same Warning.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this warning occurs because you are essentially rendering a scrollview inside a scrollview.

If you are just looking to display the items in a single scrollable list, one option is to use `.map` to add the components to your existing scrollview instead of using the Flatlist component inside.

The other way to fix this would be by using Flatlists `ListFooterComponent` and `ListHeaderComponent`. Wrap everything above your flatlist in a component and pass it into flatlists ListHeaderComponent prop, and repeat for the items beneath your flatlist using ListFooterComponent.

Finally, if it's working fine with it being wrapped in the ScrollView, you can always just hide the warning using

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native'



YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'VirtualizedLists should never be nested', // TODO: Remove when fixed
])
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to that you are nesting a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView`, so the gesture system might have trouble understanding which scroll to use...

I suggest you to have something more like this to prevent the scrolling to overlap:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={
      <Fragment>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          preview={{ uri: listing.images[0].thumbnailUrl }}
          tint="light"
          uri={listing.images[0].url}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SomeComponent>Hi</SomeComponent>{' '}
        </View>
      </Fragment>
    }
    ListFooterComponent={
      <Fragment>
        . . . .
        
        <SomeComponent>
          More of these that should generate a scrool
        </SomeComponent>
      </Fragment>
    }
  >
    ...
  </FlatList>
</View>
```

This way you only have a single `FlatList`, but you' re still able to have content being shown before or after. You can play around with the `FlatList` props, depending if you want the header and footer to always be visible or not.